# Mean value theorem for multivariable integrals (With slightly less demands)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Define: A set $ E \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is **admissible** if it is bounded in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ and its boundary is a set of measure zero (in the sense of Lebesgue).

Now let $ f $ be an integrable functio over an admissble and connected set $ E $, such that $ f $ is also continuous. Prove that there exists $ \zeta\in E $ such that  $ \intop_{E}f\left(x\right)dx=f\left(\zeta\right)\mu\left(E\right) $.

Now if I know that the set $ E $ is a closed set then it would be a compact set and I know how to prove it given this information. But as I see it, $ E $ is not necessarily a closed set. So what can do I in this case?

Thanks in advacnce.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $|E|>0$, otherwise there is nothing to prove.
If $f$ is continuous on $E$ then
$$
\inf f(E) \leq \frac{1}{|E|} \int_Ef(x) dx \le \sup f(E).
$$
Since $E$ is connected, $f(E)$ is an interval and, therefore, it contains any point in between $\inf f(E)$ and $\sup f(E)$.

Comment: How do you know that the infimum and the supremum exists?

Comment: They always exit. It is only the max and the min that you don't know if they exist. But you don't need to know that.